# aggregate data source and pseudo join?

Tags: 2010, content-query-web-part, xslt-list-view-web-part, data-form-web-part, aggregation

Is it possible to use the aggregatedatasource to show all "parents" and theirs "children" where at least one "children" is created by the current user ?

To be more clear, imagine the following :

- parent 1

  - child 1.1 created by Alice
  - child 1.2 created by Bob
  - child 1.3 created by Bob
- parent 2

  - child 2.1 created by Bob
  - child 2.2 created by Bob
- parent 3

  - child 3.1 created by Charly
  - child 3.2 created by Bob
  - child 3.3 created by Alice

I'd like to build a webpart that will show when Alice display the page:

- parent 1

  - child 1.1 created by **Alice**
  - child 1.2 created by Bob
  - child 1.3 created by Bob
- parent 3

  - child 3.1 created by Charly
  - child 3.2 created by Bob
  - child 3.3 created by **Alice**

thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep.  Use your aggregated data source in a DVWP and create a variable and assign your name to it.  Then use an XPATH filter with the variables you created to run a test (choose or if) against the xpath return value and your variable.  Then it's just a matter of formatting.